# What is your position in the company?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, business-language

When someone sent you an email without signature, how to ask - in a polite way - which is the person's position in the company ?

Comment: First, there isn't enough context for anyone to answer this question.  Is this a message from a complete stranger?  Is this a message to you alone, or to a large group of people?  Are you obliged to answer?  Second, take a look at http://workplace.stackexchange.com/  and consider whether your question is about English or about how to navigate a tricky workplace situation.

Answer (score 1):

Any question you ask will be polite or impolite depending only on the recipient's perception.  If they don't feel like telling you, it doesn't really matter how you ask.

I would go with:

> May I please ask your job title?

Or perhaps even justify the question with something like:

> May I please ask your job title so I know when to include you in discussions?

Honestly, though - and this isn't an answer about the English language - I'd just ask somebody who already knows their position in the company if possible.